# Lucene Query Syntax of field with a space

Tags: lucene

I am trying to perform two Lucene queries. The first one works. The second does not. My first query looks like this:

```
level:"dangerous"
```

My second query looks like this:

```
IP address:"11.22.333.444"
```

I'm not getting a query error. However, I know there are documents with the matching IP address. For that reason, I suspect the space between "IP" and "address" is causing the problem. However, I'm not an expert in Lucene. So, I'm not sure if I'm correct in that.

When I look at my result set using PostMan, I can see a document with a field that looks like this:

```
"IP address": "11.22.333.444"
```

Can someone please tell me if my query is correct? Or, if I'm missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that space is the problem.

The space in a field name is allowable, but conflicts with query parser syntax.  You are essentially running two subqueries combined as `SHOULD` clauses (ie, an `OR`):

- `IP`
- `address:"11.22.333.444"`

You can escape the space using a single slash before the space, like:

```
IP\ address:"11.22.333.444"
```

Comment: I suspect there was a type in the original post. The trick is to use a single slash to escape the space and then it works. As in: IP\ address:...